# ¿Select Dinamico no me carga con Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

**Nota: Como no sabia que poner en el titulo simplemente. si esta mal pueden corregirlo**

Estoy un poco confundido, no se exactamente por que se da este problema en especifico. Si alguien pudiera explicarme porque sucede así, los pongo en contexto:

```
<div id="box_provincias">
    <select name="provincias" id="provincias">
        <option value="1">Álava</option>
        <option value="2">Albacete</option>
        <option value="3">Alicante</option>
        <option value="4">Almería</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="box_localidades"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#provincias").change(function() {
        var parametros = "?id=" + $("#provincias").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php" + parametros,
            success: function(r) {
                $('#box_localidades').html(r);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Como miran arriba con esto lo que intento es como hacer un `select` dinámico que conforme selecciones un `select` diferente. El **id="box_localidades"** invocaría su listado de localidades según el estado sea el `select`. De la forma que mencione arriba me funciono.

El problema me da específicamente cuando lo hago de esta manera.
no entiendo porque funciona de la manera de arriba y como esta la de abajo no me da el mismo resultado:

Gracias

```
<div id='Charge'></div>

$.ajax('http://sitelicon.eu/test/').done(function(data) {
    $("#Charge").html(data);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#provincias").change(function() {
        var parametros = "?id=" + $("#provincias").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://sitelicon.eu/test/ajax_localidades.php" + parametros,
            success: function(r) {
                $('#box_localidades').html(r);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Que error te da consola?

Comment: un advertencia amarilla sale esto : ```[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.```